# Appearance settings of the website,problem with CSS

Tags: asp.net

Am running asp.net web application.I need to modify the appearance of my web page..I want to   bring a table that contains some labels and textbox to the centre of the page..I changed the align to centre..it is not working...i changed the padding pixels which is in default...it is also not working out...i feel CSS in not applying..can anyone help me to slve this..

Answer (score 0):

you can use margin to bring it to center

Answer (score 0):

Check that the CSS file path you are provided in page is right.

for example :

```
<link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

the above line should be inside head tag

here "css" folder is inside project root directory, and site.css is inside that "css" folder

so check the path of css file

Answer (score 0):

Check the path which the browser attempts to resolve in e.g. firebug or fiddler, and check the status and content of the response. A common scenario is that you haven't granted permission or authorised access to the CSS folder so you'll get a 4xx range response, or worse a 200 response which is actually a custom error page.